# Kustomize error: base/file is not or below env/main/file

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kustomize

I am trying to apply kustomize from `env/main/kustomization.yaml` directory

```
kubectl diff --kustomize .
```

which gives error:

```
`: security; file 'base/replacements/xxxx.yaml' is not in or below 'env/main'
```

The above kustomization is applied on the base directory `base/kustomization`. If I run  `kubectl diff --kustomize .` directly in the base directory there is `no error`. Running from `env/main` gives the error.

contents of kustomization.yaml in `env/main`

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
- ../../base
images:
-  ecr-image

replacements:
- path: ../../base/replacements/file1.yaml
- path: ../../base/replacements/file2.yaml
- path: ../../base/replacements/file3.yaml

configMapGenerator:
 - literals:
    - abc
```

contents of kustomization.yaml `base/`

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

transformers:
  - tranxformers.yaml

configMapGenerator:
  - name: xxx
    namespace: name-space
    envs:
     - configs/env-file

resources:
  - applications/deployment.yaml
```

Why replacements files path are causing this error? What is the cause of this problem? I am keen to understand the flow of kustomize in a better way.

**Update:**

- if I move the replacements directory inside env/main directory there is no error. But this is not ideal since I want to use the base directory even for replacements
- I did tried to use replacements as components but it's not replacing the desired values

Comment: Don't [re-post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76809652/3001761).

Comment: I actually deleted the previous  question because there was some file name errors!

Comment: But you evidently know [how to edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76809652/revisions).

Comment: It has the names of the files which was confidential which couldn't be removed frome dit history !

Comment: As you can see above it's still there anyway. It's not clear what you think people could conclude from the innocuous words used in the names, but now it looks like you're defining the same file multiple times.

Comment: Thank you I will make it more easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

A `kustomization.yaml` cannot refer to files outside of its own directory. It can only refer to (a) resources or (b) [components](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/components.md), both of which are directories that contain their own `kustomization.yaml` file.

If you have a group of transformations -- such as several replacement definitions -- put them in a component, and the include that component as necessary.

E.g., you could structure things like:

```
.
├── base
│   └── kustomization.yaml
├── components
│   └── common_replacements
│       ├── file1.yaml
│       ├── file2.yaml
│       ├── file3.yaml
│       └── kustomization.yaml
└── envs
    ├── dev
    │   └── kustomization.yaml
    └── main
        └── kustomization.yaml
```

Where `components/common_replacements/kustomnization.yaml` would look like:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component

replacements:
  - file1.yaml
  - file2.yaml
  - file2.yaml
```

And then in `env/main.kustomization.yaml` you would have:

```
components:
  - ../../components/common_replacements
```

And similarly anywhere else you want to use the same replacements.

Comment: I tried your solution but I think replacements are not being applied even though there is no error. I can confirm that replacements are not being applied with your solution because I kept replacements in env/main and it worked and now when I trying your solution and applying kustomize the earlier value ( when replacements worked) is overridden

Comment: Can you tell me why replacements when used as components didnt work?

Comment: I cannot, because replacements work just fine when defined in a component. [Here's an example](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-76712848-kustomize-replacements/tree/main) I put together for a previous question on this topic. I'd be happy to take a closer look at your use case, but you would need to update your question to include a complete reproducer -- a minimal configuration that reproduces that problem you're asking about.